# HTTP GET in JSON within an API

Tags: json, api, post, get

How to I do a HTTP GET request of some data in JSON format, from one API endpoint and POST it back to another API endpoint.

Comment: you should include the code you have tried if you want help from the community otherwise your question may be ignored ore deleted for being too broad..

Comment: Please review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: provide your piece of code or explain what you have tried so far

Answer (score -1):

-(void)GetRequest{

```
//Init the NSURLSession with a configuration
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

//Create an URLRequest
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your URL"];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//Create task
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    //Handle your response here
   // NSLog(@"resultsDictionary is %@",response);


}];

[dataTask resume];
```

}